# Controlar Alto de celdas en AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, table

Tengo una app en *AndroidStudio* la cual carga datos desde una BD en *MySQL*. Para mostrar dichos datos, lo hago a través de un `TableLayout`. El problema, es el siguiente, me gustaría que se respete un alto específico. Cuando estuve realizando pruebas, se mostraba con zonas de menor caracteres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando quise mostrar una nueva zona con más caracteres, sucedió lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La celda con la zona **Sudeste Cepillada** aumentó su altura quedando más alta que las que le siguen a su derecha.

Este es el *xml* de la actividad:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/layoutTabla"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollvertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollhorizontal"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tabla"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:stretchColumns="1"
                            android:shrinkColumns="0">
                        </TableLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Esta es la clase *Tabla*:

```
public class Tabla {
    // Variables de la clase

    private TableLayout tabla;          // Layout donde se pintará la tabla
    private ArrayList<TableRow> filas;  // Array de las filas de la tabla
    private Activity actividad;
    private Resources rs;
    private int FILAS, COLUMNAS;        // Filas y columnas de nuestra tabla

    /**
     * Constructor de la tabla
     * @param actividad Actividad donde va a estar la tabla
     * @param tabla TableLayout donde se pintará la tabla
     */
    public Tabla(Activity actividad, TableLayout tabla)
    {
        this.actividad = actividad;
        this.tabla = tabla;
        rs = this.actividad.getResources();
        FILAS = COLUMNAS = 0;
        filas = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
    }

    /**
     * Añade la cabecera a la tabla
     * @param recursocabecera Recurso (array) donde se encuentra la cabecera de la tabla
     */
    public void agregarCabecera(int recursocabecera)
    {
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutCelda;
        TableRow fila = new TableRow(actividad);
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        fila.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);

        String[] arraycabecera = rs.getStringArray(recursocabecera);
        COLUMNAS = arraycabecera.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < arraycabecera.length; i++)
        {
            TextView texto = new TextView(actividad);
            layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(arraycabecera[i]), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            texto.setText(arraycabecera[i]);
            texto.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            texto.setTextAppearance(actividad, R.style.estilo_celda);
            texto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda_cabecera);
            texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);
            fila.addView(texto);
        }
        tabla.addView(fila);
        filas.add(fila);
        FILAS++;
    }

    /**
     * Agrega una fila a la tabla
     * @param elementos Elementos de la fila
     */
    public void agregarFilaTabla(ArrayList<String> elementos)
    {
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutCelda;
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow fila = new TableRow(actividad);
        fila.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);

        for(int i = 0; i< elementos.size(); i++)
        {
            TextView texto = new TextView(actividad);
            texto.setText(String.valueOf(elementos.get(i)));
            texto.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            texto.setTextAppearance(actividad, R.style.estilo_celda);
            texto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda);
            layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(texto.getText().toString()), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);
            fila.addView(texto);
        }
        tabla.addView(fila);
        filas.add(fila);
        FILAS++;
    }

    /**
     * Elimina una fila de la tabla
     * @param indicefilaeliminar Indice de la fila a eliminar
     */
    public void eliminarFila(int indicefilaeliminar)
    {
        if( indicefilaeliminar > 0 && indicefilaeliminar < FILAS )
        {
            tabla.removeViewAt(indicefilaeliminar);
            FILAS--;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve las filas de la tabla, la cabecera se cuenta como fila
     * @return Filas totales de la tabla
     */
    public int getFilas()
    {
        return FILAS;
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve las columnas de la tabla
     * @return Columnas totales de la tabla
     */
    public int getColumnas()
    {
        return COLUMNAS;
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el número de celdas de la tabla, la cabecera se cuenta como fila
     * @return Número de celdas totales de la tabla
     */
    public int getCeldasTotales()
    {
        return FILAS * COLUMNAS;
    }

    /**
     * Obtiene el ancho en píxeles de un texto en un String
     * @param texto Texto
     * @return Ancho en píxeles del texto
     */
    private int obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(String texto)
    {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        p.setTextSize(50);

        p.getTextBounds(texto, 0, texto.length(), bounds);
        return bounds.width();
    }
}
```

Y así es como cargo los datos:

```
private void listaPreciosPapa() {//método que nos trae los precios
    //stringrquest para traer los datos del php
    //lo ideal sería parsear el array
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {//try para atrapar errores si es que los hay
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);//creamos un array que dibuja los datos del php
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {//ciclo para ya saben qué
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);//creamos un JSON objeto
                            //le agregamos los campos pertinentes, requisito funciona: nombre de los campos de la bd
                            String zona = jsonObject1.getString("nombreZona");
                            String premin = jsonObject1.getString("precioMinimo");
                            String premax = jsonObject1.getString("precioMaximo");
                            String prom = jsonObject1.getString("promedio");

                            //probando la tabla
                            Tabla tabla = new Tabla(ListaPreciosActivity.this, (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabla));
                            tabla.agregarCabecera(R.array.cabecera_tabla);
                            ArrayList<String> elementos = new ArrayList<String>();
                            zona = zona.replaceAll(" ", "\n");
                            elementos.add(zona);
                            elementos.add(premax);
                            elementos.add(premin);
                            elementos.add(prom);
                            tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();//captamos el error
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });//same bug, different error
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ListaPreciosActivity.this); //esto ya fue explicado
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

¿Alguien me puede decir como hago para que se mantenga el alto?

Comment: Los elementos de las celdas los estas creando dinamicamente

Comment: Sí, es una tabla dinámica

Comment: se deve conservar los valores de una cadena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba ajustando el parámetro *height* cuando usas `TableRow.LayoutParams()` en el método *agregarFilaTabla* (ya que es allí donde se ingresa el ancho y alto), dale un tamaño fijo.

Ejemplo de la modificación:

```
/**
 * Agrega una fila a la tabla
 * @param elementos Elementos de la fila
 */
public void agregarFilaTabla(ArrayList<String> elementos)
{
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutCelda;
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TableRow fila = new TableRow(actividad);
    fila.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);

    for(int i = 0; i< elementos.size(); i++)
    {
        TextView texto = new TextView(actividad);
        texto.setText(String.valueOf(elementos.get(i)));
        texto.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        texto.setTextAppearance(actividad, R.style.estilo_celda);
        texto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda);


// En esta línea yo puse un 100 para probar
        layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(texto.getText().toString()), 100);
        texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);
        fila.addView(texto);
    }
    tabla.addView(fila);
    filas.add(fila);
    FILAS++;
}
```

---

Una solución alternativa también podría ser usando [setShrinkAllColumns(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout#setShrinkAllColumns(boolean)) que en este caso te serviría para ver las columnas encogibles.

[Aquí](https://columna80.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/diseos-android-bsicos-tablelayout/) puedes ver ejemplos del método mencionado, el cambio en este caso seria cuando defines tu tabla:

```
this.tabla = tabla;
this.tabla.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
```

Espero te funcione. Saludos ;)

Comment: Lo probé, pero no ha funcionado tan bien. Pues, según el dispositivo se altera. Ejemplo: en Motorolas, la tabla se ve de manera correcta pero en Xiaomi no

Comment: Agregué una solución alternativa que podrías probar o incluso combinar ambas soluciones ;)